# How to gsub() consecutively over vector without copy and paste

Tags: r

I have several string replacements I need to achieve consecutively in a vector, (i.e., the next replacement is based on the previous replacement), but I don't want to copy and paste multiple times as I'm trying to optimize my code blocks.

I have a vector:

`initNames <- c("A.-.B", "A.B", "A0", "1 2", "AB BC")`

I want to replace elements within the vector so that the final output looks like this:

`newNames <- c("A - B", "A B", "Ao", "1.2", "AB.BC")`

I can achieve that this way:

```
newNames <- gsub(".-.", " - ", initNames, fixed = TRUE)
newNames <- gsub(".", " ", newNames, fixed = TRUE)
newNames <- gsub("A0", "Ao", newNames, fixed = TRUE)
newNames <- gsub("1 2", "1.2", newNames, fixed = TRUE)
newNames <- gsub("AB BC", "AB.BC", newNames, fixed = TRUE)
```

But I want to do it in an optimized way. I tried this:

```
toreplace <- c(".-.", ".", "A0", "1 2", "AB BC")
replacements <- c(" - ", " ", "Ao", "1.2", "AB.BC")

initNames <- initNames %>% as_tibble()

newNames <- purrr::accumulate(initNames,
                          \(x, y) {
                            gsub(x = toreplace, y = replacements, initNames, fixed = TRUE)
                          })
```

But it only changed the first value. I also tried using `purrr::map2()`, but got a list in which each element is replaced, but does not base it on the previous replacement:

```
newNames <- purrr::map2(toreplace, replacements, ~gsub(.x, .y, initNames, fixed = TRUE))
```

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you timed the replacements you already had?  It's hard to believe that they would take long enough to justify worrying about optimization.  On the other hand, the intent is very clear.    I'd stick with code that works, is clear, and is fast enough.

Comment: Thanks for that. I read that you should never copy and paste more than twice, so I've been trying to write code that avoids that. But I'm glad to know that's not the general consensus, and that method works just fine.

Comment: I just timed your original code and the accepted answer.  Yours was about 5 times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace_all` can do that:

```
library(stringr)

res <- str_replace_all(initNames, fixed(toreplace), replacements)

# check    
identical(res, newNames)
## [1] TRUE
```

Note that that replaces toreplace[i] in initNames[i] with replacements[i].  If what is wanted is to apply all the replacements to each element of the input then use this instead.  In the example in the question it makes no difference but in general it may.

```
library(stringi)

res2 <- stri_replace_all_fixed(initNames, toreplace, replacements, 
  vectorize_all = FALSE)

# check    
identical(res2, newNames)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

Definitions from question:

```
initNames <- c("A.-.B", "A.B", "A0", "1 2", "AB BC")
toreplace <- c(".-.", ".", "A0", "1 2", "AB BC")
replacements <- c(" - ", " ", "Ao", "1.2", "AB.BC")

 newNames <- c("A - B", "A B", "Ao", "1.2", "AB.BC")
```

Comment: Added stringi solution.

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `mapply`, using `grepl` to find each match.

```
ggsub <- function(data, Find, Replace){
  c(unlist(mapply(\(x, y) 
      gsub(x, y, data[grepl(x, data)]), Find, Replace)), 
    grep(paste(Find, collapse="|"), data, invert=T, value=T))}
```

```
ggsub(initNames, c("\\.", " ", "0"), c(" ", ".", "o"))
   \\.1    \\.2       1       2       0 
"A - B"   "A B"   "1.2" "AB.BC"    "Ao"
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for taking the time to figure that out <3